# @Valid @RequestBody failed to validate incoming Json with wrong input

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger

I want to validate incoming RequestBody.My controller API is,

```
@RequestMapping(value = {
        POSRequest.REQUEST_SEPARATOR + Request.UPDATE_URL,
        method = RequestMethod.PUT,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ApiOperation(value = "Update .”,
        response = SuccessResponseDTO.class, ,
        produces = "application/json", httpMethod = "PUT")
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK",response = SuccessResponseDTO.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized",response =ErrorResponseDTO.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden",response = ErrorResponseDTO.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found",response = ErrorResponseDTO.class)
})
public @ResponseBody
SuccessResponseDTO update(HttpServletRequest request,
                             @ApiParam(required = true, type = "String", value = " ") @RequestParam(value = “id”, required = true) String id,
                             @ApiParam(required = true, type = "String", value = "  ") @RequestParam(value = "documentNumber", required = true) String documentNumber,
                             @ApiParam(required = true, type = "String", value = " ") @RequestParam(value = “Sid”, required = true) String sid,
                             @ApiParam(required = true, type = "UpdateDTO", value = "Update payload json ")  @Valid @RequestBody UpdateDTO pdatePayload) throws IOException {
    authorizeRequest(request, anId);
    UpdateDTO posDTO = UpdatePayload;
    UpdateAction<UpdateDTO> action = new UpdateAction(Constants.ACTION_UPDATE, DTO, principal);
    action.addAdditionalParams(Constants.KEY_INPUT_DOC_NUMBER, documentNumber);
    action.addAdditionalParams(Constants.KEY_INPUT_SUPPLIER_AN_ID, sid);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    action.addAdditionalParams(Constants.CONTENT, gson.toJson(DTO));
    return updateService.update(action);
}
```

I am using annotation `@Valid` with `@RequestBody`, expecting it to validate the input JSON. Invalid input JSON where the user sends non-mapping attribute is passing through, `API` just ignoring the non-mapping fields without any error.

e.g.  `UpdateDTO` contains `setter` and `getter` for the fields String name, String status.

User request with an invalid field,

```
{
"name":"my update",
"invalid_field":"abc"
}
```

converted into `UpdateDTO` and non-mapping fields are ignored. I expected it to error out with invalid input.

Can you please suggest to me ? How can I make it work? please let me know if you need any input

I have included the following maven dependencies,

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Check this tutorial. You will find the answer [https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialize-json-unknown-properties](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialize-json-unknown-properties)

Answer (score 5):

You have misunderstood the usage of `@Valid`. The `@Valid` annotation is used to validate beans with constraints like `@NotNull`, `@Size`, `@Min` etc as per the **JSR 380 specification**. For eg, in case you want to have a validation on the `name` field of `UpdateDTO` class such that `name` should never be null, you can use `@NotNull` on the `name` field, then have `@Valid` on the `UpdateDTO` object in your controller method. This would ensure that whenever the request is made without passing the `name` field, the validation would fail and an exception would be thrown accordingly.

For your use-case where you want an exception thrown when an unknown field is sent as part of the request, since you are using spring-boot which uses Jackson for serialization/deserialization, you just need to provide a configuration to enable deserialization failure on encountering unknown properties. This can be done by enabling it via properties as below:

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES=true
```

or by defining a `@Bean` as below:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    return Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
            .json()
            .featuresToEnable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> Use @Validated annotation to top of the controller class 
>    and add this in the controller class

```
 /**
 * Exception handler for ConstraintViolationException.
 * @param exception ConstraintViolationException
 * @return error message
 */
@ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public @ResponseBody String annotationExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException exception) {
    return exception.getMessage();
}
```

it handle invalid input of user.